# On the Definition of Smooth Map in Differential Topology

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $X$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. In differential topology (see e.g. Milnor, Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint or Guillemin and Pollack, Differential Topology), we call $f$ *smooth* if for any $x \in X$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth (in the usual sense, that is with continuous partial derivatives of all orders) map $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $F$ and $f$ coincide on $U \cap X$. This definition has clearly a *local* nature and it is for sure the right definition to give in differential topology.
My curiosity is its relation with its *global* counterpart. Call $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ *globally smooth* if there is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $X$ and a smooth function $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $F|_X = f$.

The two definitions are very different in nature, but are they actually different? In other terms, is there some example of a smooth function which is not globally smooth?

Thank you very much for your attention.

**NOTE**. The fact that the definition of smooth function has a local nature is clear. We can make it even more clear by stating the following simple

**Proposition**. Let $X$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. $f$ is smooth if and only if for any $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f|_N$ is smooth.

*Proof*. If $f$ is smooth, then for any nonempty subset $S$ of $X$, $f|_S$ is smooth. Conversely, assume that for any $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f|_N$ is smooth. Let $x \in X$ and let $N$ be such a neighborhood. Then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth function $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $F$ and $f$ coincide on $U \cap N$. If $V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ such that $V \subset N$, there is an open subset $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V= W \cap X$. But then $U \cap W$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $F|_{U \cap W}$ is a smooth map, and $F|_{U \cap W}$ and $f$ coincide on $ U \cap W \cap X = U \cap V \subset U \cap N$.

Comment: I think this works if $X$ is locally closed because smooth functions are a sheaf and open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are paracompact (but I can’t find a reference). I’m not sure what to expect in the general case.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace: I think this may be too bold. We don’t know that the (a priori different) function extensions actually coincide on the intersection of two distinct $U_x$…

Comment: @Aphelli You're right, they coincide on non open sets (I delete my comment to avoid confusion)

Comment: What goes wrong with the "usual" partition of unity construction?

Comment: @TedShifrin: nothing, I think…